# Speed of urllib.urlretrieve vs urllib.urlopen

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to download SEC filings directly from the SEC ftp server.  When I use `urllib.urlretrieve(url,dst)`, it takes significantly longer than when doing something like `page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()` followed by  `writeFile.write(page)`.  As an example:

```
from time import time
import urllib
url = 'ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/886475/0001019056-13-000804.txt'

t0 = time()
urllib.urlretrieve(url,'D:/temp.txt')
t1 = time()
t = t1-t0
print "urllib.urlretrieve time = %s" % t


t0 = time()
writefile = open('D:/temp2.txt','w')
page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
writefile.write(page)
writefile.close()
t1 = time()
t = t1-t0
print "urllib.urlopen time = %s" % t
```

When I run this, I get 33 seconds for `urllib.urlretrieve` and 2.6 seconds for the `urllib.urlopen` block.  If I watch the D drive, the full ~5.6MB is downloaded very quickly, but then it hangs for ~30 seconds.  What is going on here?  I can proceed with my project using the `urllib.urlopen` method, but would like to know for future projects.  I am running Windows 7 professional 64-bit and this is Python 2.7.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you're thinking about future projects you should be using `urllib2` or even [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, `requests` (as of 2.0.0) doesn't support ftp prefixes, but `urllib2` does.

Comment: I don't see an analogous function to `urllib.urlretrieve` for the `urllib2` library.  I can do the same thing as the second block using `urllib2.urlopen()`, but this doesn't really help me.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Timing is a funny thing, especially considering the stateless environment of the web.

While I don't have a smoking gun, I would recommend you take a look at the [source for urllib](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r27/Lib/urllib.py?view=markup) (as of 2.7).

You can see at line 69: `def urlopen`, and line 87: `def urlretrieve`. Both create a `FancyURLopener()`, but call separate functions within the class.

My best guess is the delay revolves around either:

1. Windows file handlers, opening, closing, etc.
2. DNS resolution (Less likely, since the file resolves and downloads with 5.6 seconds as you claim.

You could always hack your `urllib.py` source to print out timings of each sub-function call, even if only temporarily to trace down the hangup. To locate where your installation is storing urllib.py, use the following:

```
import urllib
print urllib.__file__
```